# Haskell strange type inference narrowing

Tags: haskell, ghc, type-inference, ghci

GHCi 7.8.3

```
filter (\(a,b) -> a>0) :: (Ord a, Num a) => [(a, t)] -> [(a, t)]
```

as expected ^

```
fstGt0 xs = filter (\(a,b) -> a>0) xs
```

is the same type too, but

```
fstGt0 = filter (\(a,b) -> a>0)
```

infers as

```
fstGt0 :: [(Integer, t)] -> [(Integer, t)]
```

Why?
Furthermore, if I define fstGt0 in interpreter with

```
let fstGt0 = filter (\(a,b) -> a>0)
```

it has expected type.

Comment: GHCi inference rules differ to those of GHC IIRC.

Comment: We need a template answer for monomorphism-restriction questions...

Comment: @leftaroundabout Why? Can't we just close pretty much all of them as dupes?

Comment: @Cubic: yeah... though often the questions are in fact substantially different. They aren't really duplicates at all, they just happen to be all about problems caused by the same root (“of all evil”), which is the Monomorphism Restriction. I suppose that's still in scope of what the _close as duplicate_ feature is there for, but still...

Comment: @leftaroundabout (or anybody else who is interested in this task) Ping me: I have a long list of questions on my disk that are of this form. Might save you a bit of searching to find out all the things you need to address in such a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like the effect of *Monomorphism Restriction* (introduced because otherwise there were incoherent things in the language, and the language designers couldn't come up with something less ugly): if something looks like a value rather than like a function (with arguments), it can't be polymorphic. (Your `fstGt0` has no arguments.)

There is an ordered set of *default types* which are tried to be substituted in order to automatically satisfy the Monomorphism Restriction. (That's why you got `Integer`.)

As for the GHCi part of the question, I'm not sure. I'm not sure how much GHCi's `let` are similar to compiled `let`, and whether there are some exceptions in the Monomorphism Restriction for code in `let`-expressions.

There must be a flag to turn the restriction off.

Comment: namely  `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction`, but it's turned off by default in GHCi

Comment: Hm, weird behaviour (unexpected). They've should at least added some sort of warning to ghc when it has to do it.

Comment: @DanM. Run ghci with `-Wall` - there is a warning when constraints are resolved by defaulting, it's just not turned on by default. Note that while the monomorphism restriction is annoying in ghci at times, you pretty much always want it in normal haskell files. (interestingly enough, I actually have to set -XMonomorphismRestriction on my ghci to get it to do that).

Comment: @Cubic Thanks. It's just complicates point-free programming.